# Waiting for send function in phpmailer or mail function complete

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I make a form for user register, when they click Submit button a active email will be sent to their email and go to index page. This is code

```
/*
code config for PHPMailer
*/
$mail->Send();
header("location: index.php");
```

The issue is  take some second to wait for 
    $mail->Send();
or
    mail($user_email,$subject,$content)
complete. How can when user click submit button, will go to index.php and email will be sent in a background. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

PHP is single-thread which means it will just work it's way though the script. It will wait when doing something and continue when it's finished.

What you want is not possible.

You COULD however try an approach with Ajax and two separate scripts.

Comment: @Hoclamweb - Explain what? Single thread means that PHP can only do one thing at a time in a script. If you want to do what you ask, you must divide the job in more scripts and run them at the same time. Ajax is used for this.

Comment: Yes I understand single thread in PHP, I don't know how to use ajax in this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional parameter to mail funciton

```
$additional_parameters = "O DeliveryMode=b";
mail ($to, $subject,$message, $additional_headers, $additional_parameters)
```

hoping it will work

Answer (score -1):

May be try something like this:

```
<?php if( $mail->Send(); ) { header("location: index.php"); }
```

Comment: It still waits for $mail->Send();